# How do I declare multiple array variables on one line - python

Tags: python, syntax, variable-declaration

In order not to use so many lines to declare variables like this:

```
open = []

high = []

low = []

close = []
```

Could I do something like this:

```
open,high,low,close = []
```

That actually works

Comment: That last line should not work. How did it work for you? The last line *unpacks* whatever is in the right hand side, so your list should have had four items to unpack

Comment: How will it not throw an error?

Comment: Me too, in both py27 and py3 and it produces `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` in py27 and `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)` in py35.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The example in your question will not work. It will raise a `ValueError`. This is because Python is attempting to unpack four values into `open`, `high`, `low`, and `closed`, but if finds no valuest(this will raise an error in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x):

```
>>> open, high, low, close = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
>>>
```

To initialize all of the lists variables on the same line, you need to provide a list for *all* four variables:

```
>>> open, high, low, closed = [], [], [], []
>>> 
>>> open
[]
>>> high
[]
>>> low
[]
>>> closed
[]
>>>
```